# what is wrong in this statement php doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, php-5.3

I'm trying make a validation in my db using doctrine where I just need to make this statement in SQL like, `Select * from usuarios where usuario_email = someEmail`

After I click the submit button from my form,
I instantiate the class `UsuarioDao`, from a script that includes `bootstrap.php` (from doctrine default)
and pass with parameter `entityManager`. Then I call method `validacao()`, I know I don't doing of form right, not using filters etc, I just want understand how doctrine works. Here are my model doctrine

```
/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="usuarios") 
 **/
class Usuario {
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue **/
    public $usuario_id;
    /** @Column(type="string") **/
    public $usuario_nome;
    /** @Column(type="string") **/
    public $usuario_email;
    /** @Column(type="string") **/
    public $usuario_senha;
    /** @Column(type="string") **/
    public $usuario_status;

    //getters and setters omited

}
```

Here my classDao for my model

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
class UsuarioDao{

    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $entityManager;

    function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager) {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function validacao(){

        $usuario = new Usuario();
        $usuario->setUsuario_email($_POST['email']);
        $usuario->setUsuario_senha($_POST['senha']);
        $em = $this->entityManager;
        $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u FROM Usuario u WHERE u.usuario_email ='. $usuario->getUsuario_email());
        $resultado = $query->getResult();
        return $resultado;
    }

}
```

I get this wrong:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException'
>   with message 'SELECT u FROM Usuario u WHERE u.usuario_email
>   =ricardo@gmail.com' in C:\wamp\www\RicardoOfficial\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException.php
>   on line 52

and this

> Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 54:
>   Error: Expected end of string, got '@' in
>   C:\wamp\www\RicardoOfficial\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException.php
>   on line 52

Comment: check the variable name`$usuario->setUsuario_nome($_POST['email']);
        $usuario->setUsuario_senha($_POST['senha']);`  they are diffreent. Camel case problem. check once

Comment: try changing WHERE u.usuario_email ='. $usuario->getUsuario_email()); to WHERE u.usuario_email ='. $usuario->getUsuario_email()) . "'";  - it looks like you're not closing the single quotes around the email address

Comment: $usuario->setUsuario_senha($_POST['senha']) will be for set the password, it dont is in use yet, i trying just with email first, but get this fail that i post in question

Comment: dbinns66 are this bro i surround the  variable $usuario->getUsuario_email()) with single quotes and work. should be more easy :). anyway now is work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot quotes surrounding the value.

```
    $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u FROM Usuario u WHERE u.usuario_email ="'. $usuario->getUsuario_email(). '"');
```

If you have a problem with SQL statements best thing to do is copy the query you got paste it to your SQL editor and see normally you would have spotted the mistake quiet fast.